# Sane hash for SIMD values?

Tags: c++, hash, simd, unordered-map

I'd like to use as a test a simple hashmap with `__m128i`, but C++ complains that the hash function is not compatible:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/[...]/c++/v1/__hash_table:880:5: error: static_assert failed due to requirement [...] "the specified hash does not meet the Hash requirements"

    static_assert(__check_hash_requirements<_Key, _Hash>::value,
    ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

In file included from [...] note: in instantiation of template class [...] requested here
    std::unordered_map<__m128i, std::size_t> hmap;
```

Now, I could provide a hash function just by using a code similar to this:

```
    class hash128i
    {
    public:
        std::size_t operator()(const __m128i &r) const
        {
            return something;
        }
    };
```

With `something` invented by me, like `OR`-ing high and low 64-bits of the `__m128i`, and then use `std::hash`.

Given the sensitive nature of hash functions, however, I don't know if this approach is sane.

What would be a good C++ hash function for a `__m128i` (or other SIMD variable)?

Comment: Completely up to you. The goal is to have `something %  num_buckets` be as uniformly distributed as possible.

Comment: Probably XOR would be better (but still not good).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The practical quality of a hash function depends somewhat on what properties you need and how your data is distributed.

If you do not have to defend against malicious input trying to clog your table with lots of colliding values, a rather simple function should be sufficient.

For short integers Chris Wellons has done quite a bit of [analysis](https://nullprogram.com/blog/2018/07/31/) using his [hash-prospector](https://github.com/skeeto/hash-prospector) program.

A good 64-bit function mentioned by him is the following, found [here](http://xoshiro.di.unimi.it/splitmix64.c):

```
uint64_t splittable64(uint64_t x)
{
    x ^= x >> 30;
    x *= UINT64_C(0xbf58476d1ce4e5b9);
    x ^= x >> 27;
    x *= UINT64_C(0x94d049bb133111eb);
    x ^= x >> 31;
    return x;
}
```

You could hash both halves of the 128 bit integer and combine them via XOR, rotate one of them if you expect the halves to be identical often. So your solution might look something like this:

```
class hash128i
{
public:
    std::size_t operator()(const __m128i &r) const
    {
        uint64_t lower_hash = splittable64(static_cast<uint64_t>(r));
        uint64_t upper_hash = splittable64(static_cast<uint64_t>(r >> 64));
        uint64_t rotated_upper = upper_hash << 31 | upper_hash >> 33;
        return lower_hash ^ rotated_upper;
    }
};
```

If your hash table shall be resistant against malicious input, you might want to use a keyed hash function seeded with a random key. Have a look at [SIPHash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SipHash).

Comment: `r >> 64` isn't a valid way to access the upper 64-bit element of a `__m128i`, but otherwise ok.  With AVX512 you'd extract the high half to another vector and use a SIMD rotate, then XOR and extract.  (Or even rotate upper and lower halves by different amounts, with a [`vprolvq` per-element-variable-count rotate](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/VPROLD:VPROLVD:VPROLQ:VPROLVQ.html)).  That might be a decent plan even without AVX*, emulating the rotate as 2 shifts + OR.  But extracting to both halves to scalar is probably better in that case.

Comment: If you want a narrower hash value that's actually practically usable directly as an index into a table, you might do more shuffling and XORing in SIMD.